# Далай-лама или далай-лама?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Розенталь и gramota.ru говорят, что титул "далай-лама" пишется со строчной буквы. А как быть с конкретными людьми? Скажем, титул нынешнего, шестнадцатого далай-ламы тоже пишется со строчной буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно правилам названия титулов пишутся с маленькой буквы. Прописная буква в тех же названиях встречается в официальных документах. Не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете в виду под "конкретными людьми''.

***Дополнение.***

Если учитывать, что далай-лама у буддистов используется в качестве имени собственного, можно и с прописной. Опираясь на правило:

> Пишутся с прописной буквы индивидуальные названия, относящиеся к области религии и мифологии, например: Христос, Будда, Зевс, Венера, Вотан, Перун, Молох. Таким образом, Далай-Лама можно считать индивидуальным именем собственным и писать с прописной буквы. Тем более, в СМИ встречается и прописная и строчная. Конкретного правила о написании этого слова в качестве имени собственного нет.

Comment: **Sergey Kim** указал на то, что у буддистов "далай-лама" используется не только в качестве титула, но и в качестве имени собственного для текущего обладателя этого титула (далай-лама других имён не имеет).

Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: @Серж Поскольку последний комментарий является существенной частью ответа на вопрос, было бы здорово включить его в текст самого ответа.